# How to set y axis from zero in my graph matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, yaxis

I wrote my script like the one below

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with open('J:\Kuliah\Original\BOC0-power.data') as f:
    plotting=f.readlines()
    t = [line.split()[0] for line in plotting]
    d = [line.split()[1] for line in plotting]
    

plt.plot(t, d)
plt.xlabel('x - axis')
plt.ylabel('y - axis')

plt.title('Line graph!')

plt.show()
```

and the result was :
[image: my graph]

the y axis can't start from zero and the value on the axis was not sorted

Comment: Are you sure this is the plot for the code? The title and labels say otherwise.

Comment: You need to convert the strings to float: `float(line.split()[0])` and `float(line.split()[1])`